# Is it possible to serve gzipped content with the correct headers on Akamai NetStorage?

Tags: gzip, akamai

As an Akamai NetStorage customer I would like to upload static files and have NetStorage serve them as gzipped content with the correct content-encoding header.

Preferably it would encode these files from the originals to serve accept-encoding gzip or not gzipped content.

In Amazon S3 you do this by adding metadata but I'm unable to locate a similar process for this on S3.

Comment: are you going to use netstorage as an origin only or are you asking about serving content from netstorage directly? if your case is the latter i don't think there's a way to apply any rules for delivery

Comment: Serving directly from netstorage, not as an origin. I don't believe the client is using the edge product

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No - it is not possible. Akamai is a CDN and its value is in content delivery via edge network. NetStorage is intended to serve as an origin for the edge network. Optimizing delivery from NetStorage would undermine the very business model.